# Google sign-in working in the Android app but does not connect to YouTube API

Tags: amazon-web-services, youtube, aws-lambda

What I am trying to achieve is integrating Google Sign-in functionality to Android which generates an id token which is sent to the backend to authenticate using the google-auth NodeJS library. The token is verified in AWS lambda but the id token generated from Google sign-in is not able to connect to YouTube data api.

Comment: There is probably not enough information here to help you. What is the response from the Google Sign-In API? Are there any logs in any part of this system that will give some clues as to what the issue is?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.